# Link to php script

Tags: php

I have a script which I can run from windows console writing "php backup.php". How to create a link to run it directly from desctop?

Answer (score 6):

Windows? You create a batch file ("name.bat") with notepad, and you put the php command there. You will be able to double click it. Add the "pause" command at the end of your script, if you want to prevent the window from closing after the script completes.

Comment: I did:

@ECHO OFF
php C:\backup.php
PAUSE

Answer (score 1):

Use the windows context menu to select **New->Shortcut** and proceed accordingly from there on.